# How to write qunit test for the on-change event of a dropdown?

Tags: jsp, vue.js, qunit

I have a Jsp file with following code:

```
 <fieldset class="cd">
                    <label class="select icon icon-toggle180" v-bind:for="'DropdownList'">
                        <select id="Dropdown" v-bind:name="'Dropdown'" v-bind:id="'Dropdown'" v-on:change="DropdownListChanged($event, 'DropdownChanged')">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            <option>Option 1</option>
                            <option>Option 2</option>
                        </select>
                   </label>
 </fieldset>
```

The Javascript file uses vue.js.It has a following function definition for `DropdownListChanged()`

```
DropdownListChanged: function (e, type) {
                        if ((e.target.value != "" || e.target.value !="Select") && e.target.value == "Option 1") {
                            this.policy = "A";
                        }
                        if ((e.target.value != "" || e.target.value !="Select") && e.target.value == "Option 2") {
                            this.policy= "B";
                        }

                    }
```

**Now I want to write qunit test to test this javascript function**. But I am not sure how should I mock the `$event` object and test the function.